# Bash calculate x months back from todays date

Tags: bash, date

I am working with this date format

```
20130702
```

and would like to calculate 15 months back.

I am currently using

```
date -v 10m
```

With my current date format how can I create an if statement that checks if date is no later than 10 months

Thanks all!!

Comment: This seems like two loosely related questions in one. Can you edit your question to make it clearer exactly what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a easy one:

```
date -d '20130702 - 15 months'
Mon Apr  2 00:00:00 BST 2012
```

If you want to keep same format:

```
date -d '20130702 - 15 months' +%Y%m%d
20120402
```

WRT to you if statement, you can convert to epoch first:

```
#! /bin/bash

date="20130702"
date_epoch=$( date -d "20130702" +%s)
_10months_ago=$(date -d 'now -10 months' +%s)

if [ "$date_epoch" -lt "$_10months_ago" ];then
    echo "$date was before last 10 months"
else
    echo "$date is within last 10 montsh"
fi
```